# Merging two dataframes with different lengths

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can I merge two pandas dataframes with different lengths like those:

```
df1 = Index  block_id   Ut_rec_0
       0       0           7
       1       1           10
       2       2           2
       3       3           0
       4       4           10
       5       5           3
       6       6           6
       7       7           9


df2 = Index  block_id   Ut_rec_1
       0       0           3
       2       2           5
       3       3           5
       5       5           9
       7       7           4

result = Index  block_id    Ut_rec_0    Ut_rec_1
           0       0           7           3
           1       1           10          NaN
           2       2           2           5
           3       3           0           5
           4       4           10          NaN
           5       5           3           9
           6       6           6           NaN
           7       7           9           4
```

I already tried something like, but it did not work:

```py
df_result = pd.concat([df1, df2], join_axes=[df1['block_id']])
```

I already tried:
df_result = pd.concat([df1,df2,axis = 1)
But the result was:

```
Index   block_id    Ut_rec_0    Index   block_id    Ut_rec_1
  0            0          7         0.0   0.0         3.0
  1            1          10        1.0   2.0         5.0
  2            2          2         2.0   3.0         5.0
  3            3          0         3.0   5.0         9.0
  4            4          10        4.0   7.0         4.0
  5            5          3         NaN   NaN         NaN
  6            6          6         NaN   NaN         NaN
  7            7          9         NaN   NaN         NaN
```

Comment: pd.concat([df1, df2],axis=1)

Comment: did not give the expected result

Comment: I refaced the question with the output using pd.concat([df1, df2],axis=1) output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas.DataFrame.join` can "join" dataframes based on overlap in column data (or index). Something like this will likely work for you:

```
df1.join(df2.set_index('block_id'), on='block_id')
```

Comment: I found that solution: result = df1.merge(df2, on='block_id', how='left')

Comment: You're question is answered then?

Answer (score 0):

As @Wen said best would be using `concat` with `axis` as `1`, like the below code:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2],axis=1)
```

Comment: I refaced the question with the output using pd.concat([df1, df2],axis=1) output

Answer (score 0):

you need, [pd.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with outer join,

```
pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['Index','block_id'],how='outer')
#[out]
#Index  block_id    Ut_rec_0    Ut_rec_1
#0      0               7       3.0
#1      1               10      NaN
#2      2               2       5.0
#3      3               0       5.0
#4      4               10      NaN
#5      5               3       9.0
#6      6               6       NaN
#7      7               9       4.0
```